# Exclude project from build configuration in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild, alm

How do you exclude a project from the solution that is built by TFS?

I have:

- Created a configuration and unticked build for the project I want to exclude.
- Checked in the changes to the sln from above file to TFS.
- Triggered a build under TFS with the build configuration I have added.

This doesn't work. When I build locally I can see that the build skips the project (I get "Project not selected to build for this solution configuration"). When I look at the TFS build log, I can confirm that the same configuration is used, and that the project gets built.

Comment: Copy the build command (C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe /nologo /noconsolelogger "C:\Builds\20\TFS\...\solution.sln") from TFS build log and run it manually on the build server.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some sort of bug. Had the same issue.

I resolved it by manually removing the offending project from the solution file.

Find the project's GUID in the solution file - note it is the last GUID on the line, the first one seems to be the solution GUID.

Then find this project GUID and the various configurations for it in the `GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms)` section of the solution file and remove the ones you want.

Not ideal, but it works.